# MongoDB Add Array From One Collection To Another Collection Using Aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have two MongoDB collections.  I would like to add the points array from sourceCollection as a new field to targetCollection matching on the legacyId fields using aggregation.  How can I do this?

**targetCollection:**

```
db.targetCollection.insert({"legacyId": 1, "name": "Name 1", "type": "Building"});
db.targetCollection.insert({"legacyId": 2, "name": "Name 2", "type": "Area"});
```

**sourceCollection:**

```
db.sourceCollection.insert({"legacyId": 1,
                            "points": [ {"latitude": "lat value 1", "longitude": "long value 1"} ] });
db.sourceCollection.insert({"legacyId": 2,
                            "points": [ {"latitude": "lat value 2", "longitude": "long value 2"}, 
                                        {"latitude": "lat value 3", "longitude": "long value 3"}, 
                                        {"latitude": "lat value 4", "longitude": "long value 4"} ] });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/). This requires that the `targetCollection` has a unique index on `legacyId`, which can be created with

```
db.targetCollection.createIndex({legacyId: 1}, {unique: true})
```

The aggregation pipeline must remove `_id` before the `$merge`, otherwise an error is generated.

```
db.sourceCollection.aggregate([{$unset: "_id"},
                               {$merge: {into: "targetCollection", on: "legacyId"}}])
```